# How to make an extension for nvarchar max? Fluent nHibernate + Nhibernate

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I been looking around for how to do this but I can't get it to work. I seen many tutorials that using

PropertyMap or IProperty but I can't figure out what using statement to use and VS intellisense does not know either

http://serialseb.blogspot.com/2009/01/fluent-nhibernate-and-nvarcharmax.html

I am using fluent nhibernate and nihbernate 3.0. So did they remove these?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tested, but try extending `PropertyBuilder`, using the method `PropertyBuilder.Length(int length)`.

https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/blob/master/src/FluentNHibernate/Mapping/Builders/PropertyBuilder.cs

Comment: naw does not seem to even give me .Length method.

Comment: Well... then I guess you're not using trunk? :)

Comment: Guess not I am using v1.x build #694

Comment: I am using now what I think is the trunk version(it was imported through nuget) and it seems now I have to use property builder but property builder does not seem to have a .Length()

Comment: I think I got it to work. I was having weird problems where everytime I tried to add the reference I got "failed to reference module. Probably, reference will create circular dependency between projects" but a couple "clean solutions" did the trick.

Comment: Wierd, I just checked the source code... there is a Length() method. Line 97.

Answer (score 0):

It seems if I used PropertyPart that works.